# Test plans to be written according to design spec?

Tags: testing, specifications

Is not it unusual? It seems that I should write the test plans just by the interface design spec but it is not telling much. Is there any approach that could be used here or I simply cannot produce any relieble tests based just on that? Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test ?  Just an interface, or a system using that interface ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say its not possible to write test plan based on just design specification. However, V-model says for each item (on the left) there is a equivavelent on the "test" (right) side but I think it is not considered to be a test plan.

If you have just a brief design draft of the system, what would you test? Of course, something can be "tested" - if the design says it is connected to SQL, you can test that the connection is being established and alive but to me it does not seem worthy..